# Change image on all ImageViews' by the help of getTag() in TicTacToe

Tags: java, android

I'm making a TicTacToe, in which there is a background of a grid and it contains nine ImageViews'.

There is a reset button at the bottom, on clicking it all the ImageViews' should disappear(setting them to white color).

This is the initial state when the app is launched, after clicking the reset button again this should appear

[image: This is the initial state when the app is launched, after clicking the reset button again this should appear]

**Here's the MainActivity.java:-**
What to write in btnTap function which is set to be OnClick of reset button so that my purpose is fulfilled?

(any other logic other than getTag() will be appreciated)

```
package com.example.honey1.tictactoe;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  

{

int active = 0;
int[] state = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};


public void btnTap(View view)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if(state[i]!=2)
    {
   //What to write here?
    }
    }

}
public void imgTap(View view) {
    ImageView img = (ImageView) view;
    int tapped = Integer.parseInt(img.getTag().toString());

    if (state[tapped] == 2) {
        if (active == 0) {

            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.cross);
            img.animate().setDuration(1000).rotation(90);
            active = 1;
            state[tapped]=0;
        } else {

            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle);
            active = 0;;
            state[tapped]=1;
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

        @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**XML file:-**(This app contains only of one activity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context="com.example.honey1.tictactoe.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.911"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:onClick="btnTap"
        android:text="@string/btn"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.553"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.941"
        tools:text="@string/btn" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/h"
    android:tag="0"
    android:layout_width="69dp"
    android:layout_height="57dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:onClick="imgTap"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.086"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.223"
    app:srcCompat="@android:color/background_light" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/f"
    android:tag="1"
    android:layout_width="69dp"
    android:layout_height="57dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:onClick="imgTap"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.223"
    app:srcCompat="@android:color/background_light" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/b"
    android:tag="2"
    android:layout_width="69dp"
    android:layout_height="57dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"

    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:onClick="imgTap"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.899"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.223"
    app:srcCompat="@android:color/background_light" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/i"
    android:tag="3"
    android:layout_width="69dp"
    android:layout_height="57dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:onClick="imgTap"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.101"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.436"
    app:srcCompat="@android:color/background_light" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/g"
    android:tag="4"
    android:layout_width="69dp"
    android:layout_height="57dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:onClick="imgTap"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.436"
    app:srcCompat="@android:color/background_light" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/a"
    android:tag="5"
    android:layout_width="69dp"
    android:layout_height="57dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:onClick="imgTap"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.899"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.436"
    app:srcCompat="@android:color/background_light"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/d"
    android:tag="6"
    android:layout_width="69dp"
    android:layout_height="57dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:onClick="imgTap"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.086"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.655"
    app:srcCompat="@android:color/background_light" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/c"
    android:tag="7"
    android:layout_width="69dp"
    android:layout_height="57dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:onClick="imgTap"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.655"
    app:srcCompat="@android:color/background_light" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/e"
    android:tag="8"
    android:layout_width="69dp"
    android:layout_height="57dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:onClick="imgTap"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.876"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.661"
    app:srcCompat="@android:color/background_light"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to identify the ImageViews or even check which ones changed, just iterate through them and set them as needed. And don't forget to set all states to 2

```
for(int index=0; index<((ViewGroup)viewGroup).getChildCount(); ++index) {
    View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)viewGroup).getChildAt(index);
    if(nextChild instanceof ImageView){
        //remove image
    }
}
```